# What do they use as money in the Tinker Bell films?

Tags: disney, tinker-bell, tinker-bell-2008

Does the Tinker Bell/Neverland universe shown in the [Disney Fairies films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_Bell_(film_series)) have any currency?

**Do they, for example, use pixie dust as a means of exchange?**

<sub><sup>I need to know for a DND campaign I am DMing!</sup></sub>

Comment: I am referring to the Disney Tinker Bell film series.

Comment: Excellent. I've retracted my close vote and created a new tag to show what universe you're asking about

Comment: "*"The greatest treasures are not gold "Nor jewels, nor works of art "They cannot be held in your hands They're held within your heart "For worldly things will fade away as seasons come and go "But the treasure of true friendship will never lose its glow"*"

Comment: I've seen all of these films and I'm reasonably certain that while the Pirates and mundanes use real money (gems, gold, coins, etc), the fairies basically live off of the land. They make most-everything that they use and what they can't make, they acquire through flotsam and jetsam

Comment: @Valorum - ... and the kindness of others together with the occasional larceny committed out of necessity.